# mongoose find query with nested array of object

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a collection of user's data with a friends list that has a nested array of objects.

```
{username: "abcd", friends: [{name: "A", status : "active", code: "X1"},{name: "B", status : "inactive", code: "X2"}, {name: "B", status : "active", code: "X3"}]}
{username: "xyz", friends: [{name: "A", status : "active", code: "X1"},{name: "E", status : "inactive", code: "X2"}, {name: "F", status : "active", code: "X3"}]}
{username: "xyz", friends: [{name: "X", status : "active", code: "X1"},{name: "E", status : "inactive", code: "X2"}, {name: "F", status : "active", code: "X3"}]}
```

I am trying to find a query with who are have friends name is "A".
I am getting two records with all data.
I tried using the below query.

```
users.find({"friends.name" : "A"});
```

Current output:

```
{username: "abcd", friends: [{name: "A", status : "active", code: "X1"},{name: "B", status : "inactive", code: "X2"}, {name: "B", status : "active", code: "X3"}]}
{username: "xyz", friends: [{name: "A", status : "active", code: "X1"},{name: "E", status : "inactive", code: "X2"}, {name: "F", status : "active", code: "X3"}]}
```

Expected Output:

```
{username: "abcd", friends: [{name: "A", status : "active", code: "X1"}]}
{username: "xyz", friends: [{name: "A", status : "active", code: "X1"}]}
```

The result should return only who have name is "A".. Other objects data should not return..

Can you help to build query like above output.

Comment: see [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/index.html) operator, you can use this in projection of find() from mongodb v4.4.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`projection`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/) in this way:

```
db.collection.find({
  "friends.name": "A"
},
{
  "username": 1,
  "friends.$": 1
})
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/yz0HXE8q0ch)